# Java Extract data based on pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a pattern extractor using java regular expressions. any help in this regard is appreciated. Let me explain with an example.

**For the following Input:**
*Steve earns 9050$. Steve fuel cost is 500$ steve food cost is 800 Jack won 10000 steve marks in grad are 85 80 50 75 60*

**Expected Output is as follows:**

- Steve earns 9050
- Steve fuel cost is 500
- Steve food cost is 800
- Jack won 10000
- Steve marks in grad are 85 80 50 75 60

In the above string, there are a few words followed by numbers. once the numeric's are complete, i want to break the pattern into a new line.

Spaces, periods are not a concern. Extraction is more important. The number of words prior numbers may vary. for some there would be 2-3 words. for some cases, there might be 10 words prior numbers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does C++ come into the picture (and if it doesn't, why did you tag it)?

Comment: Well, the question is based on the Programming logic. Even using any external libraries, the solution could be attained. If you think, i wrongly tagged C++, please let me know, so i could edit the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern to match the sentences could be `[\D\s]+[\d\s$\.]+`, that is non-digits and spaces followed by digits, spaces, dollars and periods. To extract these in Java, you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Steve earns 9050$. Steve fuel cost is 500$ steve food cost is 800 Jack won 10000 steve marks in grad are 85 80 50 75 60";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\D\\s]+[\\d\\s$\\.]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
  }
}
```

If you expect more than dollars and periods as possible characters after the numbers, put them in the second `[]` group. If you don't want the dollars and periods in there, remove them. In that case they'll show up in the next token, though, unless you add something to the beginning of the regex that prevents the match.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\\.$][\\D\\s]+[\\d\\s]+");
```

comes to mind.

Comment: The first pattern is the correct one, which worked flawlessly. Thank you for your super fast solution.